# What does Jesus mean, 'ascending to where he was before'?

Tags: john, jesus

> So then many of His disciples, when they heard this, said, “This statement is very unpleasant; who can listen to it?” 61 But Jesus, aware that his disciples were complaining about this, said to them, “Is this offensive to you? 62 What then if you see the son of man ascending to where he was before? John 6:60-62 NASB

Answer (score 3):

Previous verses detailing the conversation preceding verse 62 provide the answer.

Verses 32-33, Jesus reminded them of the ***manna God provided from heaven***, to literally feed the Israelites in the wilderness, then said,

> "For the bread of God is He Which cometh down from heaven, and giveth
> life unto the world" (*The Companion Bible*, p1530)

Verse 42, the people could not understand this and asked,

> "How is it then that he saith, 'I came down from heaven'?" [*Ibid.*
> p1531]

This, then, gives the meaning to Jesus asking in verse 62 that, if they were offended at him speaking about being ***the bread that came down from heaven*** (vs. 58), how much more offended might they be if they saw him **ascending up to where he had been before** - **heaven**?

***'Coming down' is in contrast to 'ascending up'.*** Of course, when the disciples were with the resurrected Christ, listening to his last words to them, then they understood:

> "When He had spoken these things, while they beheld, He was taken up;
> and a cloud received Him out of their sight. And while they looked
> stedfastly toward heaven as He went up, behold, two men stood by them
> in white apparel; which also said, 'Ye men of Galilee, why stand ye
> gazing up into heaven? This same Jesus which is taken up from you into
> heaven shall so come in like manner as ye have seen him go into
> heaven." (Acts 1:9-11 *The Companion Bible*)

**Jesus meant ascending up, back into heaven, from where he had come**, in order to be born of Mary on earth.

Answer (score 2):

> What and if ye shall see the Son of man **ascend up where he was before?**
> (John 6:62, KJV)

Where was Jesus before?  He alludes to this in the previous chapter.

> I am come in my Father's name, and ye receive me not: if another shall
> come in his own name, him ye will receive. (John 5:43, KJV)

And shortly before the statement of the question, Jesus also speaks of having been sent by the Father.

> No man can come to me, except the Father which hath sent me draw him:
> and I will raise him up at the last day. (John 6:44, KJV)

A few chapters later, however, we find an explanation that more fully answers the question.

> Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my
> words: and my Father will love him, and **we will come unto him**, and
> make our abode with him. (John 14:23, KJV)
>
> Ye have heard how I said unto you, I go away, and come again unto you.
> If ye loved me, ye would rejoice, because I said, **I go unto the
> Father: for my Father is greater than I.** (John 14:28, KJV)

**Conclusion**

Jesus refers to the fact that he had come from the Father, who had sent him, and that he would return to the Father, from whence he had come.

> I came forth from the Father, and am come into the world: again, I
> leave the world, and go to the Father. (John 16:28, KJV)

Answer (score 1):

We need to take in the *context* from the previous verses. Where again, these Jews had their minds limited to the *physical* realm (Romans 8:5-7 and 1 Corinthians 2:14). They thought that Jesus was speaking of cannibalism. However, as can be clearly seen by Jesus’ later explanation at the institution of the Lord’s Supper (Matthew 26:26-28, Mark 14:22-24, and Luke 22:19-20), Jesus was speaking of the spiritual man.

Jesus stated plainly in John 6:63 that the words He was speaking were spiritual, not physical. So “*ascending to where he was before”* is speaking of the *spiritual* dimension, i.e. heaven.

This scripture, as well as Matthew 15:12, shows that people will be offended by the Gospel. In these two instances when Jesus realized He had offended the listeners, He didn’t apologize and try to make concessions to gain their acceptance. Instead, He got harder.

One common area of lack of understanding, even offence, came when Jesus was talking about the *spiritual*, but the audience was ‘thinking’ in the natural.

In verse 62, Jesus was employing the same reasoning that He used when He spoke to Nicodemus (John 3:13). In effect, He was saying, “If you find these previous statements offensive, then you will never be able to receive the fact of My ascension back to the throne of God. If you can’t handle My death for the sins of the world, then you certainly can’t handle My resurrection and ascension.”

Answer (score 1):

John 6:60-62 -s part of a series of such statements where Jesus clearly discusses His pre-existence in the presence of the the Father before His incarnation - see appendix below.

Further, not only does Jesus declare His pre-existence with the Father, he also declares His intention to return to the presence of the father following His incarnation and ministry on earth - see appendix below.

Thus, there is nothing novel in Jesus' statement in John 6:60-62.

**APPENDIX - Jesus' Pre-existence with the Father and return to heaven**

The Bible presents a simple sequence to demonstrate the eternal pre-existence of Jesus:

- Jesus existed with God in heaven and was instrumental in the creation
- Jesus became human (was incarnated)
- Jesus died and was resurrected and returned to heaven.

We see this many times in the Bible, especially in the Gospel of John, such as:

- John 1:1-3 - In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was **with God**, and the Word was God. **He** was **with God** in the beginning. Through Him all things were made, and without **Him** nothing was made that has been made.
- John 1:14 - The Word became flesh and made His dwelling among us. We have seen His glory, the glory of the one and only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth.
- John 1:15 - John testified concerning Him. He cried out, saying, “This is He of whom I said, ‘He who comes after me has surpassed me because **He was before me**.’ ” [this, despite the the fact that Jesus was (humanly speaking) six months younger than John.]
- John 1:18 - No one has ever seen God, but the one and only Son, who is Himself God and is at the Father’s side, has made Him known.
- John 3:13 - No one has ascended into heaven except the One **who descended from** heaven—the Son of Man.
- John 3:16, 17 - For God so loved the world that He gave His one and only Son, that everyone who believes in Him shall not perish but have eternal life. For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but to save the world through Him. [NOTE - God cannot send someone who does not exist!]
- John 3:31 - The One [= Jesus] **who comes from above** is above all. The one who is from the earth belongs to the earth and speaks as one from the earth. The One who comes from heaven is above all.
- John 6:38 - For **I have come down from heaven**, not to do My own will, but to do the will of Him who sent Me.
- John 8:38 - I speak of what I have seen **in the presence of the Father**
- John 8:58 - “Truly, truly, I tell you,” Jesus declared, “**before Abraham** was [born], I am!"
- John 13:1, 3 - It was now just before the Passover Feast, and Jesus knew that His hour had come to leave this world and return to the Father. Having loved His own who were in the world, He loved them to the very end. ... Jesus knew that the Father had delivered all things into His hands, and that He had come from God **and was returning to God**.
- John 16:27, 28 - for the Father himself loves you, because you have loved me and have believed that **I came from God**.  I came from the Father and have come into the world, and now I am leaving the world and **going to the Father**.”
- John 17:5 - And now, Father, glorify Me in Your presence with the glory **I had with You** before the world existed.  See also V24.

The same idea is taught in other places as well.

- Phil 2:5-8 - Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness. And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death— even death on a cross.
- Col 1:16, 17 - For in Him all things were created, things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities. All things were created through Him and for Him.  **He is before all things**, and in Him all things hold together.
- Heb 1:2, 3 - But in these last days He has spoken to us by His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the universe. The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact representation of His nature, upholding all things by His powerful word. After He had provided purification for sins, **He sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high**.
- 1 Peter 1:20 - He was chosen before the creation of the world, but was revealed in these last times for your sake.
- Rev 22:13 - I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End.”

We even find this same idea in Messianic prophecies of Jesus -
•   Micah 5:2 - But you, Bethlehem Ephrathah, who are small among the clans of Judah, out of you will come forth for Me One to be ruler over Israel— One whose origins are of old, from the days of eternity.

Thus, Jesus always existed, created the universe, was incarnated, died and rose to return to heaven.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is asking would they even believe if they saw Him ascend resurrect from the cross.

John 6:64

> But there are some of you that believe not.
> For Jesus knew from the beginning who they were that believed not,
> and who should betray him.

Christ is called Emmanuel God with us. And He is from God.
John 1 KJV teaches.

Matthew 1:23

> 23 Behold, a virgin shall be with child, and shall bring forth a son, and they shall call his name Emmanuel, which being interpreted is, God with us.

John 6:38

> “For I came down from heaven, not to do mine own will, but the will of him that sent me.”

John 3:31-36

> 31 He that cometh from above is above all: he that is of the earth is earthly, and speaketh of the earth: he that cometh from heaven is above all. etc.

John 3:13

> And no man hath ascended up to heaven,
> but he that came down from heaven,
> even the Son of man which is in heaven.

John even teaching we all come down from God. But even God did this.
Hebrews 2:14
Hebrews 1:3

Answer (score 0):

> 60 So then many of His disciples, when they heard this, said, “**This statement is very unpleasant**; who can listen to it?” 61But Jesus, aware that his disciples were complaining about this, said to them, “Is this offensive to you? 62 What then if you see the Son of Man ascending to where he was before? 63It is the spirit who gives life; the flesh provides no benefit; the words that I have spoken to you are spirit, and are life.

Translators have translated (anabainō  ἀναβαίνω) as “ascend”.

Anabainō simply means *to go up*. It is used of *going up* to a higher elevation as in climbing a mountain (Matt. 5:1, 14:23...), of Jesus *coming up* from under the water at his baptism (Matt. 3:16; Mark 1:10), of plants that *grow up* out of the ground (Matt. 13:7; Mark 4:7, 8, 32).

From the context, “coming up to where he was before”, is referring to the *resurrection* of Christ from the grave and not his forthcoming ascension.

**Christ was simply asking if they would be offended if they saw him *come up* out of the ground, be resurrected, and be where he was before - alive, and on the earth.**

Understandably, they were having great trouble grasping this totally new arrangement - spiritual food, eating his body, drinking his blood etc. - Jesus being the *true bread and drink*. Everything depending on him being raised from the dead. If they could believe that - and they soon would, it would begin to make a lot more sense.

> Our fathers ate the manna in the wilderness, as it is written: 'He gave them **bread from heaven to eat**. V 31

> it is not Moses who has given you the bread out of heaven, but it is my Father who gives you the true bread out of heaven. v32

Noticing the "bread from heaven" referring to manna; we can also understand the same analogy when applied to Jesus. He is *from heaven* simply because he is *not of this world*, having been sent by God - just as the *food* for the Israelites was. Not requiring a *reading-in* approach to the text that puts Jesus in heaven *literally* before his alleged incarnation.

Now regarding all the verses that speak of Jesus 'returning' or 'going back'.

John 16:5 But now I am going back to the Father who sent me CEV

John 16:28 now I will leave the world and return to the Father. NLT (NIV going back)

John 13:1 His hour had come to leave this world and return to the Father BSB NLT

v3 he had come from God and was going back to God ESV NIV BSB

John 20:17 go to my brothers and tell them that I am returning to him who is my Father GNT

John 14:28 should be glad I am going back to the Father CEV

ALL the words referring to rejoining the Father are added - they are not in the Greek. The case for Jesus returning is not biblical if translations have been modified to give that impression in every instance? There are plenty of warnings about false teaching, Galatians 1:8-9, 1 Timothy 1:3-4 etc.

The case then for Jesus rising to 'where he was before' - in Heaven, is then rightly dismissed as unfounded and shown to be a myth not inspired by God.